# How to fetch multiple user post?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have multiple users and i want to display each image or video that they post... now the thing is that in the firebase database is only taking the last id added i have tried different methods and algorithm and nothing seen to work.

```
var friendsArray = [String]()
    var fetchID : String?
    for i in 0...friendsArray.count{
        friendsArray.append(fetchFriend.id!)
      let id = friendsArray[i]
        fetchID = id
    }

    print(fetchID)
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(fetchID!).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        var videos = [Video]()
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let dictionary = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath(child.key)

            let userChannel = UserChannel()
            userChannel.profileImageName = fetchFriend.profileImage
            userChannel.username = fetchFriend.username
            let video = Video()
            video.thumbnailImageName = dictionary.value!["imageURL"] as? String
            video.userChannel = userChannel
            videos.append(video)
            videos = videos.reverse()
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            completion(videos)
       })
    }

  }, withCancelBlock:nil)
}
```

Comment: Give your JSON tree , not as an Image or snippet but as text

Comment: I tried but didnt work... I might have did somethinf wrong in new in firebase and this data structures is different from sql.. Can you give me an example if you can or anybody else... Thanka you alot